# Docusign Node.js api connection with api keys

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Is there any way to connect DocuSign with api keys only? I am using docusign-esign sdk. I am creating envelope at backend and send email to user to sign that.
Currently, I use to connect it with header `X-DocuSign-Authentication` and it works perfectly in dev env.
How can I connect that in Production env?

Answer (score 0):

You are using legacy auth which is not as secure as using OAuth.
We **highly recommend** that you don't use legacy auth, and in fact we would very soon require it and not allow you to create an integration using legacy authentication (X-DocuSign-Authentication header).
You can use JWT such that the user doesn't need to authenticate each time you use your app. You would only need one time consent and you'll never have to login again.
**Please don't use X-DocuSign-Authentication to ensure your app is as secure as possible!**

Comment: The thing that bothers me is, unless I'm misunderstanding your documentation and/or our salesperson, it's an additional $1.38 per envelope for the tool that provides for long-running consent (admin tools) for JWT authentication. I'm not the asker of this question, but I just wanted to comment on that. It seems pretty ridiculous that we've been able to authenticate just fine using the legacy header at our price point for years, now; but are soon going to be forced to pay an additional fee for the same service - frankly, an outrageous one, at that.

Comment: First of all, I would like to clarify for you and everyone reading - OAuth 2.0 is free. JWT is free. There's no additional cost to use OAuth 2.0.
Also, if you choose to use JWT, you and/or your customers do not have to use admin consent. Even that is free.
If you have further questions on pricing - please contact the sales team. I focus on technical answers in stackoverflow.

Comment: You are correct, but as I stated, I'm specifically talking about admin consent. Any other OAuth-based method of authentication with DocuSign would mean a significant change to our current flow, whereas the user would have to create a DocuSign account to provide their own consent, which in our case does not make sense.

Comment: I don't think I understand your scenario. Why can't you use a fixed system account for all API calls?

Comment: Because it requires the "Access Management with SSO" feature, which is an additional cost.

Comment: Where did you see this? you can hardcode a none-SSO account as your system account, without SSO AFAIK

Comment: I have created a new SO question, here, so we do not continue to clutter up this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474448/since-docusign-legacy-header-auth-is-no-longer-supported-and-oauth-authenticati

Comment: This particular question wasn't asked by me.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Inbar. Apologies for the sidebar conversation, here - my question (linked above) has been answered, and additional context/details have been provided there.