# Since DocuSign legacy header auth is no longer supported, and OAuth authentication with the end user does not make sense for us, what are our options?

Tags: docusignapi

We currently use the legacy header method of authenticating with the DocuSign REST API for embedded signing ceremonies, and are looking to migrate our method of authentication to one that is fully supported by DocuSign. The signer, however, should not need to authenticate with DocuSign to sign this document. It is not a legally binding contract, but a document in which we collect information in order to perform a background check of the signer. The signature is simply for attesting that the information they have provided is accurate, and a paper or eSignature is required for this in the state of Illinois. What are our options?

**EDIT**: Based on similar questions I've seen here and in other forums, it seems that the documentation for this could be better. The part I was hung up on was obtaining consent for the JWT Grant authentication process. The impression is that the end user (either the signer or the sender), via the client application or service, would need to grant their consent via authenticating with DocuSign each time something needed to be signed or sent for signature. If you are using an integration such as ours, attempting to keep DocuSign as invisible as possible, this would not be an option. This is not the case. The URL constructed in Step 1 of [this process](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) is actually meant to be constructed manually, by the developer, as part of the development process, and navigated to in a browser, where the developer will log in with the DocuSign account that is meant to be used for the integration.

Comment: I should mention that it has already been suggested that we look at the Access Management with SSO enterprise-level feature, but that would be a significant cost increase for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON Web Tokens Authentication (JWT) and with [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) you only need a single system user that would be use to make API calls.

End-users won't need to log-into your application.

On other notes, since you wrote "The signature is simply for attesting that the information they have provided is accurate," I would suggest you look into using [DocuSign Click](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/click101/). A clickwrap is exactly what you need for this and you won't even need to make API calls from the server once you set it up.

Comment: The end users are the potential customers - not employees of our organization. Signatures are required. The user fills out a form on our web site, we dynamically generate a PDF with the information they've provided, and then send the PDF over to DocuSign for signature and also for payment via PayPal/BrainTree. The signature must appear in conjunction with the information the user has provided.

Comment: sure, all of this can be done with JWT without end-users logging to DocuSign if that's your concern.

Comment: and also without end-users being members of your account.

Comment: With admin consent, correct? https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/

Comment: You can do this without admin consent with individual consent. I don't see any requirement that should change this.

Comment: I guess I'm just not following. The link you provided - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/ - indicates that either individual or admin consent is required. Individual consent requires the end user to have an account with DocuSign and to authenticate with DocuSign in this process; and admin consent requires the use of the Admin tool (which is an additional cost to us) to provide single-user consent to the application. So, what am I missing, here?

Comment: " Individual consent requires the end user to have an account with DocuSign and to authenticate with DocuSign in this process"
Not accurate. You don't need the end-user, you just need a system user that would be used for API calls. The end-user just uses an app front end, the back-end users JWT with some other user. Not a problem.

Comment: How is that user set up, and how is consent acquired for that user, if not with the admin tool?

Comment: you can set it up yourself, any user will do. You can get consent manually for that user outside your app.

Comment: How? I would appreciate if you could modify your answer, and provide step-by-step instructions with screenshots that show how to create the user and how to provide consent for this type of integration.

Comment: All this information is on the site. I recommend you try it. I can't repeat everything in this answer/.

Comment: I'd love to try it. Please, provide me with a link to where I can find this information on your website. I'd love to bring this into a chat, because we are currently considering other options, and it would be wonderful if we could get this to work.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/n there's a video too. You can also use SDKs if you use one of the six coding languages we use. That would make it even easier with our Quickstart

Comment: The documentation is misleading - the instructions to establish consent need to be more clear in that I, as a developer, need to physically construct the consent URL and actually navigate to it in a browser to grant consent. The way it reads, Step 1 appears to be something that I would have the application do, rather than something I actually do myself. However, now when I use the SDK, the call to GetUserInfo() returns a user, but the List<Account> list is empty. Where do I go from here?

Comment: First off, the documentation is not misleading. I told you to do it yourself, since you don't want your users to have to do it. It's not either/or.

Comment: as for userInfo() it should include one ore more accounts, unless something is wrong. How are you making this call? did you get a valid token?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did get a valid token, and passed it along to the GetUserInfo() method. I do get a user back, but the accounts list is empty.

Comment: The user I'm attempting to use was created back in 2017. Perhaps there is something missing on DocuSign's end that would associate it to an account? I created a separate user and tried with it and it worked. However, we'd like to use our existing user so as to preserve our envelope history with that user.

Comment: I would try to create a new free developer account and see if you can work with that one. It's possible somehow you have a user without accounts, it's odd, but it can happen.

Comment: We're going with a new user in our production account - that seems to be working. I've accepted your answer. Thank you for your help. My apologies for giving you a hard time. I've made an edit to the question to provide more context/details for any future developers.